# Creating a line graph in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod

I am using this data:

```
StockData <- getSymbols("XOM", auto.assign=FALSE, from="1984-01-01")
```

I am running through the data testing a moving average crossover combination

```
FindPnL <- function(StockData, MA1, MA2, SL, LS){
 PnL_value <- numeric(0)
 Day_value <- character(0)
 for(Day in 1:7890){
  Signal <- CheckCross(...)
  cc <- Transaction(...)
  PnL <- cc$a
  Day <- cc$b
  PnL_value[n]
  totalPnL <- totalPnL + PnL
  Day <- Day + 1
 }
 df <- data.frame(Days = Day_value, Prof = PnL_value)
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Prof)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
 return(totalPnL)
}
```

Here is my code for Transaction that I use as well as a simple cross check.

```
Transaction <- function(Buy, Sell, PnL, Day, SL, LS, StockData) {
  P1 <- StockData[[Day, 4]]

  s_purch <- as.integer(100000/P1)
  P2 <- NULL
  profit_loss <- NULL
  if(Buy){
    p_up <- P1*(1+LS)
    p_down <- P1*(1-SL)
    repeat {
      if(Day>7890){
        break
      }
      if(StockData[[Day, 4]]>= p_up){
        P2 <- StockData[[Day, 4]]
        break
      }
      if(StockData[[Day, 4]]<= p_down) {
        P2 <- StockData[[Day, 4]]
        break
      }
      Day <- Day + 1
    }
    if(is.null(P2)){
      Buy <- FALSE
    } else {
      profit_loss <- (P2 - P1)*s_purch
      PnL <- PnL  + profit_loss
      Buy <- FALSE
    }
  }
  if(Sell) {
    p_up <- P1*(1-LS)
    p_down <- P1*(1+SL)
    repeat {
      if(Day>7890){
        break
      }
      if(StockData[[Day, 4]]>= p_up){
        P2 <- StockData[[Day, 4]]
        break
      }
      if(StockData[[Day, 4]]<= p_down) {
        P2 <- StockData[[Day, 4]]
        break
      }
      Day <- Day + 1
    }
    if(is.null(P2)){
      Buy <- FALSE
    } else {
      profit_loss <- (P1 - P2)*s_purch
      PnL <- PnL + profit_loss
     Sell <- FALSE
    }
  }
  results <- list(a = PnL, b = Day)
  return(results)
}

CheckCross <- function(MA1Prev, MA2Prev, MA1Value, MA2Value) {
  #Check for a cross
  Buy <- FALSE
  Sell <- FALSE
  if(MA1Prev<MA2Prev){
    if(MA1Value>MA2Value) {
      #Cross to the upside Signal a Buy
      Buy <- TRUE
    }
  }
  if(MA1Prev>MA2Prev) {
    if(MA1Value<MA2Value) {
      #Cross to the downside, Signal a Sell
      Sell <- TRUE
    }
  }
  results <- list(a = Buy, b = Sell)
  return(results)
}
```

My goal is to plot the date on the X axis and then PnL on the Y axis. I heard that ggplot2 was a good graphing package and I tried to create a data.frame but without any success. You can see what I did in the above code.

Comment: This question could become answerable if (a) it is made reproducible and (b) you show something you have tried and explain why it's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, to answer your final question about making the line chart the built-in functions in the `quantmod` package will enable you to draw the basic graphics:

```
require(quantmod)

# Data
StockData <- getSymbols("XOM", auto.assign=FALSE, from="1984-01-01")
# Series Chart
chartSeries(x = StockData)
# Line
lineChart(StockData,line.type='h',TA=NULL)
```

***Series chart***
[image: Quantmod series chart]

***Line chart***
[image: Quantmod line chart]

Now let's say that you want to transform your data to a data frame, this code will do that:

```
XOMdta<-data.frame(Date=index(XOM),coredata(XOM))
```

Then you can use it as you would use any other data frame to compute any averages, etc. If you are satisfied with using `quantmod` to do you your graphs and you need the moving average you can use the `addMA` from the `quantmod` package. For instance, the code:

```
# Line
lineChart(StockData,line.type='h',TA=NULL) 
addSMA()
```

would give you this:
[image: Quantmod average]

The detailed option are document on the [quantmod website](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/addMA.html).